# issue with fields names when using Rails form with Angularjs client side form validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, client-side-validation, form-fields

I'm trying to use Angularjs for client-side form validation in my Rails Project. I'm using the build-in ng-show directive to display errors for form fields. The code is very simple:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), 
                              html: { novalidate: true, name: 'signUpForm'}) do |f| %>
  ...

  <%= f.email_field :email, :'ng-model'=>'user.email', name: 'uEmail', 
                              autofocus: true, required: true %>
  ...

  <div ng-show="signUpForm.uEmail.$dirty && signUpForm.uEmail.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="signUpForm.uEmail.$error.required">
      <small class="error">Tell us your email.</small>
    </span>
    <span ng-show="signUpForm.uEmail.$error.email">
      <small class="error">This is not a valid email.</small>
    </span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This gives me a nice client-side validation, but the problem is, since Rails by default gives a form field name like `model[attr]` in my case `user[email]`

However, here I give my email field a name `uEmail` and params in the post request after submit the form will be `uEmail:  'xxx@xx.xx'` which rails is unable to understand ( by default Rails is expecting something like `user: { email: 'xxx@xx.xx' ... }` )

I tried to remove `name: 'uEmail'` and fall back to Rails default `user[email]` and use something like this in `ng-show` directive

```
<span ng-show="signUpForm.user[email].$error.required">
```

But This won't work, anyone has any idea how to get around with this?

`btw: rails -v 4.0 Angularjs version: 1.0.7`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you since found a solution to this issue, I was facing the same problem, I found an issue had been opened on GitHub :

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1201

The solution is pretty simple, in your case you simply do :

```
<span ng-show="signUpForm['user[email]'].$error.required">
```